Why use struct to hold constants, and not a static class?
I've just noticed two struct objects, JwtHeaderParameterNames and JwtRegisteredClaimNames, whose only purpose is to store string constants.

Why did they make them structs rather than static classes, even though there are already some static classes for constants in the namespace?

Why would you make a struct that contains only constants or static
members?


Thanks

I think is's the memory optimisation: class instance allocates an additional memory and GC need to process this instance. Struct is GC free and does not allocate additional memory.

@vusaldev static class avoids that - as would simply not having an accessible constructor.

@vusaldev AFAIK, it is not actually applicable to static members whether it is a struct or a class since neither of them is actually initiated.

Okay, but I told about instance itself, not members

@vusaldev nobody is going to be creating instances of this type, so... there is no instance to talk about

It's a "struct"; all the fields are "strings"; all the strings are "constants"; that means it's "baked in". It's a "safe" / immutable "data object"; for lack of a better term.

@GerrySchmitz the "it's a struct" is unrelated to and incidental to all of those factors; being a struct makes no difference whatsoever, so the question of "why is it a struct?" (as opposed to the more idiomatic static class) remains valid

@Marc Gravell The why is "scope" and application. The "bigger" picture. A "value" object. A "memory wise clone".  Immutable in this case. A "class" is not a "value" object. It is none of the others by default.

@GerrySchmitz I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to say there, and how any of it applies to this choice; why does it matter whether (or not) something is a "value object" in the case of hosting some consts? We don't want or need a "value object" here. static class is absolutely the idiomatic way to express this scenario.

You're right in that the more idiomatic way of expressing this would be static class; having a struct with no fields but with these const entries is unusual and atypical. It won't actually harm anything, but it is a little weird to be able to do new JwtHeaderParameterNames() or new JwtRegisteredClaimNames(), which serve no purpose.
I'm kinda surprised it wasn't changed to static class during the review process. If there is a good reason that is relevant to this specific usage, I would expect a comment in the code (also), but I don't see one. In the absence of that: we could only speculate.
Interestingly WsTrustConstants works more like we would expect, making it even more of an oddity. It is likely that this oddness is known and acknowledged, but cannot be changed now without making it a breaking change.

I love getting your answers! Thank you. I often consider the .NET codebase to be the most correct one, but these kinds of things really confuse me and make me think there is something I don't understand/know.

It doesn't matter if you use a class or a struct. Just pick one. These constants are grouped together in a new struct (or class), because this grouping makes more sense than placing them in existing struct (or class)

Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this doesn't address my question. I will adjust the post. I am asking why they made them structs rather than static classes?
